# How to get a macos theme for the login?

Tags: release-juno, wingpanel, greeter, macintosh

I have been trying to make my computer look like MacOS Mojave and this is what I have so far:

[image: Mac Mojave themed EOS Juno]

I have everything as I want it **except** I wanted to know if there was a more Mac-esque wingpanel theme **and** is there a way to change the login screen to look like a Mac's login?

Thank you in advance!!